# "Address already in use" error when using cookiecutter-flask

Tags: python, flask, npm, webpack, cookiecutter-django

I'm on OS X 10.14.3. I'm trying to use the nifty-looking [cookiecutter-flask](https://github.com/sloria/cookiecutter-flask) project. I have followed the instructions in the README.rst:

```
cookiecutter https://github.com/sloria/cookiecutter-flask.git
# I named my test ccflask, and used pipenv
cd ccflask
cp .env.example .env
pipenv install --dev
npm install
npm start
```

The [README](https://github.com/sloria/cookiecutter-flask/blob/master/%7B%7Bcookiecutter.app_name%7D%7D/README.rst) says that at this point, "You will see a pretty welcome screen." Instead, it's just serving the directory structure inside `ccflask/`.

[image]

This seems to be because flask is never starting:

```
[FLASK] Loading .env environment variables...
[WEBPACK] Project is running at http://localhost:2992/
[WEBPACK] webpack output is served from http://localhost:2992/static/build/
[FLASK]  * Serving Flask app "autoapp.py" (lazy loading)
[FLASK]  * Environment: development
[FLASK]  * Debug mode: on
[FLASK] Traceback (most recent call last):
[FLASK]   File "/Users/nick/.local/share/virtualenvs/ccflask-bmCIsVly/bin/flask", line 10, in <module>
[FLASK]     sys.exit(main())
[…stack…]
[FLASK]     s.bind(get_sockaddr(hostname, port, address_family))
[FLASK] OSError: [Errno 48] Address already in use
[FLASK] npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
[FLASK] npm ERR! errno 1
[FLASK] npm ERR! ccflask@1.0.0 flask-server: `pipenv run flask run`
[FLASK] npm ERR! Exit status 1
[FLASK] npm ERR! 
[FLASK] npm ERR! Failed at the ccflask@1.0.0 flask-server script.
[FLASK] npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
```

I am new to npm and webpack, so I'm not quite clear what the problem is. When I search for 2992, I find it in `package.json`:

```
"webpack-dev-server": "NODE_ENV=debug webpack-dev-server --port 2992 --hot --inline",
```

and also `webpack.config.js`:

```
const publicHost = debug ? 'http://localhost:2992' : '';
```

I don't know if this looks right, but I assume so? The console spew is quite explicit about both the flask app and the webpack dev server being served from different folders on the same port. I definitely don't have anything else running on 2992, because as soon as I kill npm, localhost:2992 stops responding to web requests. I also grepped the output of `ps` to be sure. It really does seem as though the `npm start` process attempts to launch two services using the same port.

Could some dependency have changed? During `npm install`, I got these warnings:

```
npm WARN css-loader@1.0.1 requires a peer of webpack@^4.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN less-loader@2.2.3 requires a peer of less@^2.3.1 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN url-loader@1.1.2 requires a peer of webpack@^3.0.0 || ^4.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
```

But there is a `webpack` directory in `node_modules`, along with `webpack-sources` and `webpack-dev-*`… so I'm out of ideas.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was indeed a port conflict, but not with 2992. The problem was that I was already running a different flask application on port 5000. Once I turned that off, the cookiecutter code worked as expected. Thanks to [kkremitzki](https://github.com/sloria/cookiecutter-flask/issues/449) on GitHub who helped me sort this out.